# retrieve data from two table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have two tables I have to retrieve data from both table with out duplication of rows .

there is table (a)

```
BILL_DATE   BILL_AMOUNT       
----------
20160208    94  
20160208    140     
20160208    30  
20160208    25  
20160208    14  
20160208    6   
20160208    35  
20160208    20  
20160208    35
```

=======================

second table is (b)

[image]

and i want to result like

[image]

Comment: Please put the SQL you are using now to generated the result and describe how it does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clear but if you want 13 rows

```
select bill_date as "DATE", bill_date, bill_amount, null as "recharge_date" , null as "recharge_amount" 
from a
union all
select rech_date          , null     , null       , rech_date               , rech_amount              
from b;
```

Not clear how you are going to get 100, 200, 300, 400 for rech_amount

Answer (score 1):

You could use a full outer join on the date in order to take the relevant row from whichever table has it:

```
SELECT          COALESCE(bill_date, reach_date) AS [date], 
                bill_date, bill_amount, 
                reach_date AS [recharge_date], reach_amount AS [recharge_amount]
FROM            a
FULL OUTER JOIN b on a.bill_date = b.reach_date
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.but i m getting 36 rows and i want only 13 row. which is sum of two table row

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT ISNULL(X.BILL_DATE,X.RECHARGE_DATE) AS DATE,X.*
FROM (
       SELECT BILL_DATE,BILL_AMOUNT as BILL_AMT,null as RECHARGE_DATE,null as RECHARGE_AMT
       FROM Tablea
       UNION ALL
       SELECT null as BILL_DATE,null as BILL_AMT,RECH_DATE as RECHARGE_DATE,RECH_AMOUNT as RECHARGE_AMT                                                                        
       FROM Tableb
       ) X
```

Comment: its is also getting perfect rows but same amount value would be removed. or getting distinct amount.

Comment: @KrutikaPatel Updated my answer, please do check and let me know if you have any issue.